# TypeScript: how to delete the *.js.map files from the project

Tags: typescript

I had set `"sourceMap": true` in my `tsconfig.json` file. After compiling every ts file got its js.map file. I reset `"sourceMap": false` and recompiled. The *js.map files did not get deleted. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Delete them by hand?

Comment: If you're using linux/osx then: `find . -name "*.js.map" -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: This sort of thing is why I like to do out-of-source builds using the `outDir` compiler option. You just nuke your `dist` folder and rebuild.

Comment: @NitzanTomer can you write your comment as the answer? I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With a unix-based system you can use find and execute:

```
find . -name "*.js.map" -exec rm {} \;
```

I find it to be very useful.